# Magento 2 : Rewrite Method savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder

Tags: magento2, overrides, payment

I'm trying to create payment module that rewrite method `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` in model `\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement`.

Here is snippet code from my own module in file : `/app/code/Mine/Directpaym/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement" type="Mine\Directpaym\Model\DirectpaymPaymentInformationManagement" />
</config>
```

Model `/app/code/Mine/Directpaym/Model/DirectpaymPaymentInformationManagement.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Mine\Directpaym\Model;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class DirectpaymPaymentInformationManagement extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ) {
            // this method is not  called
            $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
            return $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    }
}
```

I managed to call my own method in Magento 2 community edition, but in Magento 2 Enterprise it won't work.

I already tried compile, flush cache, and static content deploy as well, still won't work.

Is there specific things I miss here?

Comment: Did you get your solution or still looking for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move you di.xml file from etc folder

```
app/code/Mine/Directpaym/etc/di.xml
```

To

```
app/code/Mine/Directpaym/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

So it called your function and working fine.